# Kitchen floor mold?

Tags: kitchens, floor

Is this mold under the tile? There was a leak. The floor is not weak when standing on it. Does the subfloor need to be removed? Or would corcobium spray do the job? And how to remove tile glue? Thanks!! [image]

Comment: Looks like mold and some wood rot.  I'd pull up the worst piece and check the joints below for damage.

Comment: If you pull to inspect for further damage, make sure to wear appropriate respirator and use whole room ventilation.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I’m going to weigh it against the opinion of the guy helping me. I now tend to try to be safe regarding mold.

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't worry about the mold.  Even if it is mold once you put your new floor on top of it (depending on floor type) the mold is embedded and won't cause problems.  Mold is almost everywhere in small quantities.  I'd expect once your flooring goes down that this would be equivalent or a smaller issues than the mold that likely coats the inside of all of your plumbing pipes.

If the floor is stable I'd just ensure the floor was dry before doing whatever you are going to do on top.

You probably just want a heavy duty floor scraping tool to remove the adhesive.

Comment: If the subfloor is solid I would agree but if it is spongy or damaged it should be replaced. Off color but solid it could stay.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I’m going to weigh it against the opinion of the guy helping me. I now tend to try to be safe regarding mold. It’s not spongy, so it’s hopeful.. the black color could be wood rot and not mold? Would corcobium be good enough?